# Speech to text in python with a WAV file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, speech-recognition-api

I try to convert a speech in a WAV file but I'm stuck here. A lot of tutorial give the same code but it doesn't work for me. Here it is:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile("hello_world.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

The "hello_world.wav" file is in the same repertory than the code. I don't have any error. The console:

```
C:\Users\python.exe "D:/voice_recognition.py"
Exception:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Help? :)

(Sorry if my English is bad)

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Exit code 0 usually means everything processed OK.

Comment: your code works fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I actually made it work. I post the code that work for me if someone have the same problem:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

hellow=sr.AudioFile('hello_world.wav')
with hellow as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

Maybe it was because I used ' instead of ".

Comment: Hello @Vincent. How to see the text output from the script. I am getting only:
Exception:

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is close; what might be happening is your source variable could have the write scope of the `with … as source:` block. By ending the `with` block; you're also unsetting the variables created for that block. If this is the issue, you could:

1. Create your variables at the script scope (i.e. not within any conditional blocks, such as after `r = sr.Recognizer()`), and only assign it value within the `with` block

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
audio = False

with sr.AudioFile("hello_world.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

2. Perform all your processing while the audio file is in-scope

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile("hello_world.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        s = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("Text: "+s)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

3. As you've done in the accepted solution above; remove the `with` block and flatten your code structure.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
audio = r.record(sr.AudioFile("hello_world.wav"))

try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `audio = r.record(source)`
make use of `audio = r.listen(source)`
it worked for me..

here is the link from where I got it. [link](https://hashedin.com/blog/how-to-convert-different-language-audio-to-text-using-python/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).