# Using Windows Speech Recognition with Python?

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition

I need to find a way to use .wav files as input for Windows Speech Recognition (the one that comes with the Windows 10 OS). The problem is that I cannot find a way to use Windows Speech Recognition in Python, unlike with Unity (which can be done by using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech). I cannot find any libraries or functions.
Is there a way this can be done with Python?

Comment: There is a post on [Speech to text in python with a WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916400/speech-to-text-in-python-with-a-wav-file) that you might find helpful.

Comment: @Seraph How can I be certain that that library uses Windows' Speech Recognition?

Comment: You should read [SpeechRecognition 3.8.1](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) documentation.  It states it supports speech recognition for [Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-services/).

Comment: @Seraph Yes, but the Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition is not the same as the Speech Recognition System that you can use on Windows OS.

Comment: Just develop a small piece of code using this module which that takes a `.wav` file as an input, and see if it produces the result you're looking for.